# Fetch only pdf and document formats from bing cognitive service

Tags: c#, bing-api

I am using bing cognitive services for fetching all the web results in C#. 
 But I am facing difficult in getting only the PDF and document file formats from bing service

```
queryString["q"] = Keyword;
queryString["count"] = "100";
queryString["offset"] = "0";           
queryString["safeSearch"] = "Moderate";
queryString["responseFilter"] = "webpages";

var uri = "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/search?" + queryString
var data = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);
```

please suggest on how to modify the code so that bing API returns ONLY PDF and document formats

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: what the exact pblm. paste the sample code you tried

Comment: **[this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37757720)** may be helpful

Comment: I think you need something like this `queryString["filetype"]="pdf"`

Comment: yes i tried this--- queryString["textFormat"] = "PDF " but showing error(Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).

Comment: refer Hakam Fastok link